# .jar is not working

Tags: java, swing, jar

I have created .jar for my below code in NetBeans, but nothing happens when I double click on the .jar, although everything is working fine from NetBeans: Please help

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/*
 * NewJFrame.java
 *
 * Created on Dec 2, 2013, 3:17:19 PM
 */
package codereview;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
//import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


/**
 *
 * @author sony
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

//Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
   Statement st = null;
  PreparedStatement pst =null;
    public NewJFrame() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        initComponents();
        //setIcon();
        reset.setEnabled(false);
        submit.setEnabled(false);
       //fillCombo();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        submit = new javax.swing.JButton();
        instruction = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        entitytype = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        username = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        psswd = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        sid = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        destination = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        install = new javax.swing.JButton();
        foldername = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        reset = new javax.swing.JButton();
        check = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        data = new javax.swing.JTable();
        add = new javax.swing.JButton();
        nameentity = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        remove = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        refresh = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Eccella Code Review Tool");
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        submit.setText("Generate Report");
        submit.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                submitMouseClicked(evt);
                submitMouseClicked1(evt);
            }
        });
        submit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                submitActionPerformed(evt);
                submitActionPerformed1(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.add(submit, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(490, 400, 200, 37));

        instruction.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 255, 204));
        instruction.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14));
        instruction.setText("     Enter The Details One-by-One and Submit:");
        instruction.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        jPanel1.add(instruction, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(250, 10, 341, 30));

        entitytype.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Folder", "Mapping", "Workflow" }));
        entitytype.addPopupMenuListener(new javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener() {
            public void popupMenuCanceled(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {
            }
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {
                entitytypePopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(evt);
            }
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {
            }
        });
        entitytype.addItemListener(new java.awt.event.ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
                entitytypeItemStateChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        entitytype.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                entitytypeActionPerformed(evt);
            }


private void entitytypeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           


}                                          

private void setItem() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException 
{
                  String folder= (String) foldername.getSelectedItem();
                  String type = (String) entitytype.getSelectedItem();
                  String i =username.getText(); 
                  String j =psswd.getText();
                  String k = sid.getText(); 
                  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                  con=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+k,i,j);
                  st =  con.createStatement();

                        rs =st.executeQuery("SELECT PARENT_MAPPING_NAME FROM REP_ALL_MAPPING");
                        while(rs.next())
                {
        nameentity.addItem(rs.getString("PARENT_MAPPING_NAME"));
        System.out.println("New object added to combo box");
                }

        rs.close();
        con.close();

}

private void submitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

}                                      

private void submitMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
//String i =foldername.getText();
//String j =entityname.getText();
//tring k = (String)entitytype.getSelectedItem();
    //result.setText("<html>"+i+"<br>"+j+"<br>"+k+"</html>");
}                                   

private void submitMouseClicked1(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     

}                                    

private void submitActionPerformed1(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        Object message = null;
//       try {
//            String i =username.getText(); 
//                   String j =psswd.getText();
//                   String k = sid.getText();
//                   String folder= (String) foldername.getSelectedItem();
//                   String name = entityname.getText();
//                   String type = (String) entitytype.getSelectedItem();
//            
//            Class<?> forName = Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
//                   con=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+k,i,j);
//                    CallableStatement csmt = con.prepareCall("{call CODE_REVIEW.PRC_WRAPPER_REVIEW(?,?,?,?)}");
//                    csmt.setString(1,name);
//                    csmt.setString(2,type);
//                    csmt.setString(3,folder);
//                    csmt.registerOutParameter(4,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
//                    csmt.execute();
//                    String message =csmt.getString(4);
//                 //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
//        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
//            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//        } 


     try {
           String i =username.getText(); 
                  String j =psswd.getText();
                  String k = sid.getText();



           Class<?> forName = Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                  con=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+k,i,j);

                  DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) data.getModel();
                  for (int count = 0; count < model.getRowCount(); count++)
                  {
                   CallableStatement csmt = con.prepareCall("{call CODE_REVIEW.PRC_WRAPPER_REVIEW(?,?,?,?)}");

               String folder=model.getValueAt(count, 0).toString();
                   String type=model.getValueAt(count, 1).toString();
                   String name=model.getValueAt(count, 2).toString();

                   csmt.setString(1,name);
                   csmt.setString(2,type);
                   csmt.setString(3,folder);
                   csmt.registerOutParameter(4,java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
                   csmt.execute();
                   String messege =csmt.getString(4);
                   }

                JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Reports are Generated");
                JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("Success!");
                dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(this.isAlwaysOnTopSupported());
                dialog.setVisible(true);

       } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       } 

}                                       

private void fillCombo() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException 

{
      check.setText("");
       String i =username.getText(); 
       String j =psswd.getText();
       String k = sid.getText();
       Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+k,i,j);
           if(con != null)
           {
             install.setEnabled(false);  
             reset.setEnabled(true);  
           }
        st =  con.createStatement();
        rs =st.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT SUBJECT_AREA FROM REP_SUBJECT");
        while(rs.next())
                {
        foldername.addItem(rs.getString("SUBJECT_AREA"));
        System.out.println("New object added to combo box");
                }

        rs.close();
        con.close();

}
private Object makeObj(final String item)  {
     return new Object() {@Override
 public String toString() { return item; } };
   }

private void usernameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

private void psswdActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                     

private void sidActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                   

private void destinationActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void installMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
                fillCombo();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
           //check.setText("Please Enter Correct Details");
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please Enter Correct Details","Message",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
       int r = 2  ;
    String i =username.getText();
    String j =psswd.getText();
    String k  =sid.getText();
    int index =k.lastIndexOf(":");
    String m =k.substring(index+1);
    String l=destination.getText();
 Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
try
{
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+k,i,j);
    pst=con.prepareStatement("SELECT OBJECT_NAME FROM USER_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = ? AND OBJECT_NAME =? ");
    pst.setString(1,"PACKAGE BODY");
    pst.setString(2,"CODE_REVIEW");
    rs =pst.executeQuery();
    System.out.println("Executed query");
    String obj = new String();
    while (rs.next())
    {
         obj = rs.getString("OBJECT_NAME");
    }
    if ("CODE_REVIEW".equals(obj))
    {
       // JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("You Have Already Done Installation, Please Go Ahead With Report Generation");
       // JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("Alert!");
       // dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(this.isAlwaysOnTopSupported());
       // dialog.setVisible(true);
         r = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,"Already Installed, Do You Want to Install Anyway","Message",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    }

            if ("".equals(obj) || r == 0)
            {
System.out.println("Start Running the batch file");
Process p = run.exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe","/c","install.bat",i,j,m,l});
System.out.println(" Batch Executed");
    }



    rs.close();
    con.close();
}

catch ( ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | IOException e)
{

}      

}                                    

private void destinationFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                        
if (destination.getText().equals("Enter Path For Report"))
        {
    destination.setText("");// TODO add your handling code here:
        }
}                                       

private void destinationFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                      
if (destination.getText().equals(""))
        {
    destination.setText("Enter Path For Report");// TODO add your handling code here:
        }
}                                     

private void sidFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                
if (sid.getText().equals("Enter DB connect string/TNS name"))
        {
    sid.setText("");// TODO add your handling code here:
        }
}                               

private void sidFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                              
if (sid.getText().equals(""))
        {
    sid.setText("Enter DB connect string/TNS name");// TODO add your handling code here:
        }
}                             

private void psswdFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                  
if (psswd.getText().equals("Enter DB Password"))
        {
    psswd.setText("");// TODO add your handling code here:
        }
}                                 

private void psswdFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                
if (psswd.getText().equals(""))
        {
    psswd.setText("Enter DB Password");// TODO add your handling code here:
        }
}                               

private void usernameFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                     
if (username.getText().equals("Enter DB UserName"))
        {
    username.setText("");// TODO add your handling code here:
        }
}                                    

private void usernameFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                   
if (username.getText().equals(""))
        {
    username.setText("Enter DB UserName");// TODO add your handling code here:
        }
}                                  

private void resetMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
install.setEnabled(true);
reset.setEnabled(false);
}                                  

private void installActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                       

private void addMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                 
                   submit.setEnabled(true);
                   String folder= (String) foldername.getSelectedItem();
                   String name = (String) nameentity.getSelectedItem();
                   String type = (String) entitytype.getSelectedItem();
                   addRow(folder,type,name);

}                                

private void entitytypeItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            

}                                           

private void entitytypePopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {                                                        
                    refreshComboBox();
//                  nameentity.removeAllItems();
//                  String tmp =(String) entitytype.getSelectedItem();
//                  String folder= (String) foldername.getSelectedItem();
//                  String i =username.getText(); 
//                  String j =psswd.getText();
//                  String k = sid.getText();
//try
//{
//            Class<?> forName = Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
//            con=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+k,i,j);
//            if ("Mapping".equals(tmp)) { 
//            String sql ="SELECT m.PARENT_MAPPING_NAME FROM REP_ALL_MAPPINGS m,REP_SUBJECT s WHERE s.SUBJECT_ID = m.SUBJECT_ID AND s.SUBJECT_AREA =?";
//            pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
//            pst.setString(1, folder );
//            rs=pst.executeQuery();
//            while(rs.next())
//                {
//        nameentity.addItem(rs.getString("PARENT_MAPPING_NAME"));
//        System.out.println("New object added to combo box");
//                }
//            }
//         if ("Workflow".equals(tmp)) { 
//            String sql ="SELECT w.WORKFLOW_NAME FROM REP_WORKFLOWS w,REP_SUBJECT s WHERE w.SUBJECT_ID = s.SUBJECT_ID AND w.SUBJECT_AREA =?";
//            pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
//            pst.setString(1, folder );
//            rs=pst.executeQuery();
//            while(rs.next())
//                {
//        nameentity.addItem(rs.getString("WORKFLOW_NAME"));
//        System.out.println("New object added to combo box");
//                }
//  }   
//         if ("Folder".equals(tmp)) { 
//            String sql ="SELECT DISTINCT SUBJECT_AREA FROM REP_SUBJECT WHERE SUBJECT_AREA=?";
//            pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
//            pst.setString(1, folder );
//            rs=pst.executeQuery();
//            while(rs.next())
//                {
//        nameentity.addItem(rs.getString("SUBJECT_AREA"));
//        System.out.println("New object added to combo box");
//                }
//  }
//        rs.close();
//        con.close();
//            
//}
//catch ( ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
//{
//   // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
//}
}                                                       

private void refreshComboBox()
{
                  nameentity.removeAllItems();
                  String tmp =(String) entitytype.getSelectedItem();
                  String folder= (String) foldername.getSelectedItem();
                  String i =username.getText(); 
                  String j =psswd.getText();
                  String k = sid.getText();
try
{
            Class<?> forName = Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+k,i,j);
            if ("Mapping".equals(tmp)) { 
            String sql ="SELECT m.PARENT_MAPPING_NAME FROM REP_ALL_MAPPINGS m,REP_SUBJECT s WHERE s.SUBJECT_ID = m.SUBJECT_ID AND s.SUBJECT_AREA =?";
            pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, folder );
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
                {
        nameentity.addItem(rs.getString("PARENT_MAPPING_NAME"));
        System.out.println("New object added to combo box");
                }
            }
         if ("Workflow".equals(tmp)) { 
            String sql ="SELECT w.WORKFLOW_NAME FROM REP_WORKFLOWS w,REP_SUBJECT s WHERE w.SUBJECT_ID = s.SUBJECT_ID AND w.SUBJECT_AREA =?";
            pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, folder );
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
                {
        nameentity.addItem(rs.getString("WORKFLOW_NAME"));
        System.out.println("New object added to combo box");
                }
  }   
         if ("Folder".equals(tmp)) { 
            String sql ="SELECT DISTINCT SUBJECT_AREA FROM REP_SUBJECT WHERE SUBJECT_AREA=?";
            pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, folder );
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
                {
        nameentity.addItem(rs.getString("SUBJECT_AREA"));
        System.out.println("New object added to combo box");
                }
  }
        rs.close();
        con.close();

}
catch ( ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)
{
   // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
}


private void removeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) data.getModel();
int i = data.getSelectedRow();
model.removeRow(i);
                JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Record Deleted!");
                JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("Success!");
                dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(this.isAlwaysOnTopSupported());
                dialog.setVisible(true);

}                                      

private void refreshActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:
     try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
         nameentity.removeAllItems();

         foldername.removeAllItems();
                fillCombo();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
           check.setText("Please Enter Correct Details");
            Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}

private void foldernamePopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {
// TODO add your handling code here:
    refreshComboBox();
}

  public void addRow(String foldername, String entitytype, String entityname)
{

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) data.getModel(); 
    Object [] row = new Object [3];
    row[0] = foldername;
    row[1] = entitytype;
    row[2] = entityname;
    model.addRow(row);
}  /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>


        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
                } catch (        SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton add;
    private javax.swing.JLabel check;
    private javax.swing.JTable data;
    private javax.swing.JTextField destination;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox entitytype;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox foldername;
    private javax.swing.JButton install;
    private javax.swing.JLabel instruction;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox nameentity;
    private javax.swing.JTextField psswd;
    private javax.swing.JButton refresh;
    private javax.swing.JButton remove;
    private javax.swing.JButton reset;
    private javax.swing.JTextField sid;
    private javax.swing.JButton submit;
    private javax.swing.JTextField username;
    // End of variables declaration


}
```

Please note I have deleted unnecessary code from the above code...

Comment: Run your jar on the command prompt using java -jar jarname.jar; likely an exception is happening that you are simply not seeing. I'm also going to make a prediction that the exception is of the "classnotfound" kind.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netbeans/lib/awtextra/AbsoluteLayout
        at codereview.NewJFrame.initComponents(NewJFrame.java:77)
        at codereview.NewJFrame.<init>(NewJFrame.java:34)
        .....37 more

Comment: Yeah, so when you run the jar outside of Netbeans then you are missing dependency jars on the classpath. That suggests to me that the project setup is not correct in some way especially in how the dependencies are managed, but I couldn't say what exactly. I would investigate the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file; what class-path line is in there (if any) ?

Comment: in MANIFEST file there is no entry, I even tried with the entry but no luck..

Comment: The .jar is working fine now, but the problem is that it is not connecting to database now, although everything is working fine in netbeans, I had already added ojdbc5.jar is in project library by going to Properties--> Libraries -->Run -->Add Jar/Folde

Answer (score 0):

Just Right click on yoru projet in netbeans and select Set Configuration> then Customize> in the window that appears provide your Main Class by clicking the browse button or writing it manually and Clean and Build again,

the main class must be specified like i told you above

Comment: are you using the same JRE which netbeans uses for launching the jar file may be the version used by netbeans is different then the one your os uses to launch jars

Comment: The .jar is working fine now, but the problem is that it is not connecting to database now, although everything is working fine in netbeans, I had already added ojdbc5.jar is in project library by going to Properties--> Libraries -->Run -->Add Jar/Folder

Answer (score 0):

Some times JDK version is the reason..try to use a latest JDK version. Did you add a Theme? I also met aproblem as I set a look and feel.. Didn't solve my problem too. Without a teme it is run well..So try without set any theme.

Comment: changed the theme to default but no luck, problem is only in this class for other classes the .jar is running fine..

Comment: The .jar is working fine now, but the problem is that it is not connecting to database now, although everything is working fine in netbeans, I had already added ojdbc5.jar is in project library by going to Properties--> Libraries -->Run -->Add Jar/Folder

Answer (score 0):

The error which I already posted above was like :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netbeans/lib/awtextra/AbsoluteLayout at codereview.NewJFrame.initComponents(NewJFrame.java:77) at codereview.NewJFrame.<init>(NewJFrame.java:34) .....37 more
```

So I changed the Layout of my JPanel to GridBagLayout and it started working now, Don't know the reason , but I am happy and thanks everyone who helped me to keep me engaged with the problem otherwise I would have given up.  Cheers